# How to get the pagename from the URL without the extension through JQuery

Tags: jquery, filenames

I have a URL:-

```
http://www.example.com/keyword/category.php
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/keyword/category.php#4
```

I need a magic abracadabra which gives me only the pagename as **category** from this URL.

Here is what I tried, and it gives **category.php**. But it has two problems. It is ugly and long and it gives me filename with an extension.

```
var currurl = window.location.pathname;
var index = currurl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var filename = currurl.substr(index);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just make this into a function as below:

```
function getPageName(url) {
    var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    var filenameWithExtension = url.substr(index);
    var filename = filenameWithExtension.split(".")[0]; // <-- added this line
    return filename;                                    // <-- added this line
}
```

Then when you need to use it:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/keyword/category.php";
var myFilename = getPageName(url);
```

All of the "ugliness" has been hidden in a function and the main code looks nice and clean!

Comment: Why is "url" included as an argument to getPageName? It is not used in the code.

Comment: A good answer but what if the filename has '.' in it? as in category.new.php?

Comment: It is possible for a querystring parameter to contain forward slashes or periods. When getting the url make sure to use: location.pathname

Answer (score 2):

For work with  querystring like http://www.example.com/keyword/category.php?parametro=teste

```
function getPageName(url) {
     var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
     var filenameWithExtension = url.substr(index);
     var filename = filenameWithExtension.split(".")[0]; 

     filename = filename.split("?")[0]; // <-- added this line

     return filename;                                  


}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getPageName() {
    var index = window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
        filenameWithExtension = window.location.href.substr(index),
        filename = filenameWithExtension.split(".")[0];  

    return filename;                                     
}
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. This is a suggestion for further improving this and future answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** If you do `.split('.')`, you will miss the base names of many URLs.

---

You can find the last forward slash and search ahead for the first `.`, `?`,  `&` or `#` to catch variations of URLs. This is probably the equivalent of PHP's [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
function getBaseName(url) {
  if(!url || (url && url.length === 0)) {
    return "";
  }
  var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
  var filenameWithExtension = url.substr(index);
  var basename = filenameWithExtension.split(/[.?&#]+/)[0];

  // Handle '/mypage/' type paths
  if(basename.length === 0) {
    url = url.substr(0,index-1);
    basename = getBaseName(url);
  }
  return basename ? basename : ""; 
}
```

and use it like so

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/keyword/category.php#4";
var file = getBaseName(url);
```

**Results:**

```
http://www.example.com/keyword/category.php#4    =>  "category"
http://www.example.com/keyword/category          =>  "category"  
http://www.example.com/keyword/category/         =>  "category"  
http://www.example.com/keyword/category?ver=1    =>  "category"  
http://www.example.com/keyword/category/?ver=1   =>  "category"
http://www.example.com/keyword/category#elem     =>  "category"
```

### [JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/sacodojize/1/watch?js,console)