# How to change colour of nav bar when on a certain page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a navigation bar on a website and I want the page name to change colour when I am on that certain page, so that when i then click another page, it goes back to it's original colour and the new page selected will change colour.

I looked around for a while trying to get it to work and all I could get was it to change colour when i clicked it, then the page loaded and it went back to it's original colour.

List:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="pages/page1.html" title="Page One">Page One</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/page2.html" title="Page Two">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/page3.html" title="Page Three">Page Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation .active {
background-color: #CF5C3F;
}

.navigation li { 

float:left; border-right:1px solid #5d5d5d; 
border-left:1px solid #929292;
width: 268px; 
height: 34px; 
border-bottom:1px solid #575757; 
border-top:1px solid #797979;
background-color:#5f5f5f;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.navigation a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? it's really annoying me.

Comment: You are performing a full page loading, so you must highlight (putting the corresponding CSS class) the correct item with some server code.

Comment: This is tagged html, css, jquery only, is that a static site ? If it is, there is no point of using jquery. Just add the class for the corresponding `li` in the html file of each page. If it's not static, you should probably update your question.

Comment: How many pages do you have on your site?

Comment: The website is being graded and I've been told to use jQuery rather than CSS for this. I've also got 3 pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the page name to change the class for you.  Here's a method to get the page name (I got it from here: [How to get the pagename from the URL without the extension through JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286384/how-to-get-the-pagename-from-the-url-without-the-extension-through-jquery)

```
function getPageName(url) {
    var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    var filenameWithExtension = url.substr(index);
    var filename = filenameWithExtension.split(".")[0]; // <-- added this line
    return filename;                                    // <-- added this line
}
```

Put an id on each link that is also equal to the page name.  Then when the page loads simply add the class, there's no need to do it on the click:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a id="page1" href="pages/page1.html" title="Page One">Page One</a></li>
        <li><a id="page2" href="pages/page2.html" title="Page Two">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a id="page3" href="pages/page3.html" title="Page Three">Page Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

$(function(){
   var currentPageName = getPageName(window.location.pathname);
   $('#' + currentPageName).addClass('active');
});
```

I'm a little lazy and didn't test this, but it should get you near to what you're looking for.

Comment: Since adding extra pages on the navigation bar, it has suddenly stopped working but I have no idea why, everything in the <script> is the same, I've not changed the CSS. it makes no sense.

Comment: Try logging the page value - console.log(currentPageName), open up the debugger (usually F12) and look at the value being written to log for the current page.  Make sure that the function is creating a clean page name, and that you are in fact using that name.  If you're using a period in the name - mypages.page1.html - it would cause an issue, the console will show you what's going on and is your best friend when debugging javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force, ugly way (I use this method all the time! :-) ) is to put a hidden div on each page:

HTML

```
<div id='selectordiv'>blue</div>
```

CSS

```
#selectordiv {
     display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var selectorvar = $('#selectordiv').html();
    if (selectorvar == 'blue')
       {
        $('whateveryouwanttochange').css('todifferentattributes');
        }

                              });
```

It could be generalized to allow you to do various things depending on the "name" of the page you put in the hidden div.

Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. The page gets reloaded after the click due to `href`
2. Adding active class on wrong element in css

You can try following code:

```
.navigation li.active {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
}

.navigation li { 

    float:left; border-right:1px solid #5d5d5d; 
    border-left:1px solid #929292;
    width: 268px; 
    height: 34px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #575757; 
    border-top:1px solid #797979;
    background-color:#5f5f5f;
}

$('.navigation a').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Also instead of `href` you can load your page in one container and then append it to your navbar instead of reloading the page